# How to disable a Azure DevOps build pipeline using Azure CLI commands

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

How to disable a Azure DevOps build pipeline using Azure CLI commands, instead of using REST API's?

Comment: When browsing the available CLI methods, it doesn't seem to be there at first sight.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/pipelines?view=azure-cli-latest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, we do not have the available Azure CLI can be used to disable build pipeline on Azure DevOps.

It seems that the only available interface is the REST API "[**Definitions - Update**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1)".

There is an item ([**`queueStatus`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1#definitionqueuestatus)) can be set in the Request Body of this API to disable the build pipeline.

```json
"queueStatus": "disabled",
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try these commandes:

- Log in to Azure DevOps using a PAT (personal access token), an Azure DevOps PAT has to be authenticated
  `az devops login --organization <organization-url> --token <pat-token>`
- Disable the build pipeline
  `az pipelines build update --id <build-id> --enabled false --org <organization-url> --project <project-name>`

hope it will be helpful.